# Counting days of specified month without duplicates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula to count unique values:

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(Tabela1[Day]; Tabela1[Day]))
```

Then I press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` and:

```
{=SUM(1/COUNTIF(Tabela1[Day]; Tabela1[Day]))}
```

First step done, it works..

---

But, when I try to use `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(Tabela1[Year-Month]; [Year-Month]; 1/COUNTIF(Tabela1[Day];Tabela1[Day]))
```

It shows `#NAME?` in the cells.. Even when I press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`.

Anyone know how to do it to work?

Thanks for your time.

---

**EDIT:** My data (Tabela1):

[image]

And the results should be in `Done (days)`:

[image]

Comment: A small amount of redacted sample data would have gone a long way toward helping us understand the layout of your structure table list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF([@[Year-Month]]=[Year-Month],[Day]),IF([@[Year-Month]]=[Year-Month],[Day]))>0,1))
```

You will need to enter this with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

Comment: Your formula shows that I worked `24` days in month `2015-07`... I think it is counting days `4` and `5` from month `2015-08`... How to avoid that?

Comment: The formula is right. Did you enter it with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER? If you only press enter, you will get 24. With CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, you will get 22.

Comment: Seeing your formula, now I understand how to do this .. I will try to achieve it .. thanks !!